# Rails Question: Why can I do these two javascript calls separately but not together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

On the homepage of my web app I'm implementing pagination with ajax as well as an autocomplete search.

The script I used for the ajax pagination is here: http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will_paginate/ajax-pagination

The script I used for autocomplete search is detailed in my own answer to this question: [Rails auto_complete tag search filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911077/rails-autocomplete-tag-search-filter/1925020#1925020)

Each of these function just fine separately, but they don't work at all together. I believe this has something to do with the controller code but I'm not sure what.

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
format.js do

    #For Auto complete
    render :inline => "<%= auto_complete_result(@search_tags, 'name') %>"

    #For Pagination with ajax    
    render :update do |page|
        page.replace 'result', :partial => "search results"
    end

end
```

If I comment out auto complete, pagination with ajax works. If I comment out pagination with ajax the autocomplete works.

What should I be doing here to make both of them work?

Comment: two render calls? didn't/don't know (if) you can do that?

Comment: The two render calls seem to interfere with each other. The one that is called first seems to work, but the second one doesn't. I'm wondering if there's a way to put it all in one render call or try and if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look around, and it doesn't look like you can call render twice. It could be passing back an error page instead of a js file, so you don't actually get to see the error, but the features don't work. You'll probably just have to mash the two render calls into one somehow, maybe manually?

Comment: sorry, didn't see your comment